# Facetime Calls on Mac: Audio/Video calling buttons greyed out

Tags: macos, iphone, audio, catalina, facetime

Topic pretty much sums it up. I have verified that I am properly set up to do cell calls over my Mac using these instructions. I've rebooted both devices a couple times now. Strangely, I can receive calls from my phone on my mac. but when I try to put a number into the Mac FaceTime app, the buttons to place the call are always greyed out and never change.

What's going on?