# Grayed Out "Audio" & "Video" call buttons on Facetime

Tags: video, facetime, call

Someone asked this question a year ago and got zero answers:

I open Facetime, which I used last week with no problem for a video call, but today the camera opens, I see myself, I see my list of contacts, but when I enter a new number to call, it doesn't activate the call buttons, for audio or video.

Anybody know what's up?

Thanks!

Comment: presumably this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387550/facetime-calls-on-mac-audio-video-calling-buttons-greyed-out There wasn't enough information to go on. Same with this one. Have you verified their number is Facetime-capable? Can they call you?

Comment: I’ve noticed significant delays with FaceTime verifying if numbers are capable of FaceTime. Have you tried waiting ~20 seconds?

Comment: Thank you it seems to have spontaneously fixed itself.